# What is an efficient way of finding the classes in a project using Eclipse's JDT?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse's `SearchEngine` class has many methods for searching, including various flavors of `search`, `searchAllTypeNames`, etc.  `searchAllTypeNames` seems to be oriented around finding the classes in a package.  What is a good strategy for finding the user-defined classes in a project?  (By user-defined classes, I mean classes for which the user has written source code which resides in that project, as opposed to classes which are imported from other projects, external jars, system libraries, etc.)

1. Use `search` with a custom `IJavaSearchResultCollector`.
2. Obtain all of the packages in the project (using `search`?), then iterate through the packages, collecting the classes using `searchAllTypeNames`.
3. Traverse the AST manually.
4. Something else.

Note, I don't really need the "most efficient" way of collecting classes.  I prefer something that is easy-to-code and reasonably efficient to something that requires large amounts of code to be more efficient.

I welcome any related, general guidance on using the `SearchEngine` methods.  I find the many options baffling.

Comment: A little more clarity on what you are trying to do would be helpful.  When you say "User-defined classes", do you mean classes in source code?  Do you want to include interfaces/enums, etc?  The best way to search will depend on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg: I've clarified the wording in the question some.  I do mean classes in source code.  I am most interested in classes with behavior, so that would include enums, but exclude interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your search criteria are fairly specific, your best bet is to traverse the Java model to find your types.

Here is a little loop that you can use:

```
    IJavaProject proj = getJavaProject();
    for (IPackageFragmentRoot root : prog.getAllPackageFragmentRoots()) {
        if (!root.isReadOnly()) {
            for (IJavaElement child : root.getChildren()) {
                if (child.getElementType() == IJavaElement.PACKAGE_FRAGMENT) {
                    IPackageFragment frag = (IPackageFragment) child;
                    for (ICompilationUnit u : frag.getCompilationUnits()) {
                        for (IType type : u.getAllTypes()) {
                            if (type.isClass() || type.isEnum()) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I recommend a loop like this rather than using the search engine since there is no easy way that I know of to use the search engine to only find source types.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I wasn't really expecting anybody to write code for me, but since you did, I'll use it gratefully.  Cheers!